# How to use callback function inside the accordion?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Need more clarification::

1. I have one table data on the top of the accordion..
2. once i will expand it i want to display the table content in the  itself
3. While collapsing i want to hide the table content

Want to use call back function inside the accordion. Can you please modify and give the me the sol

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ 
    collapsible: true                   
});
```

Comment: you really need to change the title of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`change`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#event-change) event of the `accordion` method:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
   collapsible: true,              
   change: function(event, ui) { 
      // do something here
  }
});
```

or:

```
$("#accordion").bind("accordionchange", function(event, ui) {
      // do something here
});
```

Comment: Note - As of jQuery UI 1.9.0, this is actually [`activate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate), not `change`.